# postgres backup restoration failing

Tags: postgresql, out-of-memory, psql, pg-dumpall

I am trying to restore backup taken by pg_dumpall (filesize 16 GB) command:

```
psql -f backup_filename
```

but it is showing me out of memory error and process stops.

During restore when I see duplicate window using top command it is showing 100% cpu usage. any solutions?

backup taken by

```
pg_dumpall -U username -p port --database "postgres"
```

I was trying command

```
psql -p port -U username -d postgres -f filename
```

expected output
databases getting restored
current output process gets eliminated with out of error message

Comment: Figure out the individual SQL statement that is failing.

Comment: Please quote the exact error message.

Comment: What are the hardware specifications for the machine you are restoring on?